# How can I transpose values imported via QueryTables using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have created a VBA code where it prompts for a CSV file and imports it. However, it imports values as a row.  I need them to be imported as a column.  How?

I tried setting the Range to `$B$2:$B$10`, but that did not help.
I tried searching QueryTables for "transpose data on import" directive, but so far have not found one.

Code:

```
Sub Button_Import_Click()
    
    Dim Ret
    
    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Nameplate File (*.txt), *.txt")
    
    If Ret <> FALSE Then
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
             "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Range("$B$2"))
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = TRUE
            .Refresh
            
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**Data Sample**

Filename:  `text.txt`

Data:  `product,30,370 psi,80 lbs,description,80,March,20,2021`

Expectation for Excel:

```
B2: product
B3: 30
B4: 370 psi
...
B10: 2021
```

Comment: A data sample that reproduces your problem would be useful in crafting a solution.  It does not have to be **real** data; it can be made-up but should be **representative**

Comment: Use the inbuilt tools in the `data` tab of the ribbon. There are a number of was to import files. You can then use `Table.Transpose` which is presented as a `Transpose` option within the `Transform` tab of the power query editor.

Comment: You can use `power query` to transpose data easily, there is no direct way to import data and transpose at the same time, you need to write separate program for transpose data instead

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I've added sample data and how I expect it to show up on Excel Sheet

Answer (score 0):

I ended up posting QueryTables result to an empty cell range `A20` in this case
and then using Transpose to copy over cells to the required location `B2:B10`

```
If Ret <> False Then
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Range("$A$20"))
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .Refresh

    End With
    
    'Transpose
    Dim DirArray As Variant
    DirArray = Range("A20:I20").Value
    Range("B2:B10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(DirArray)
    Range("A20:I20").Clear
    
End If
```

Comment: Yes, with your data and using the `QueryTables.Add` method, you will need to transpose **after** writing the results to the worksheeet.  If there is other data on that worksheet that might be disturbed, consider writing to a temporary or hidden worksheet, and then copy/transpose to where you really want it.  Power Query would enable a transpose before writing to the worksheet, but you'd need a named range (filled in by a VBA routine), to hold the full path of your .txt file.  Or you could write the entire Power Query code in VBA.